# C# Show list in combobox based on selection in first combobox

Tags: c#

Good day.

I just looking for a solution to my problem. I just trying to make my first program and I have encountered this problem. I have 2 comboboxes, the first one is the list of supplier and the second one is the list of items. Now I need to filter down what will show in the 2nd combobox based on the 1st combobox, but still in the 2nd combobox. It always shows all the item that is listed from my database. All data are coming from SQL Database and below is the code that I am working with:

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
  conn.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblmaster where Supplier = '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  Da.Fill(dt);

  foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
    comboBox5.Items.Add(dr["ProductCode"].ToString());
  }

  conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Try to clear the list before you add new items like this: comboBox5.Items.Clear();

Comment: I have included that and it works fine, here is my next problem, after putting that, there's only 1 result showing in the 2nd combobox, example, supplier1 has 2 items, when I select supplier1 from the 1st combobox, the 2nd combobox only showing 1 item

Comment: Clear he 2nd combobox first before loading the desired items on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear the items before the loop.

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
  conn.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "select * from tblmaster where Supplier = '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  Da.Fill(dt);

  comboBox5.Items.Clear();
  foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
    comboBox5.Items.Add(dr["ProductCode"].ToString());
  }

  conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have included that and it works fine, here is my next problem, after putting that, there's only 1 result showing in the 2nd combobox, example, supplier1 has 2 items, when I select supplier1 from the 1st combobox, the 2nd combobox only showing 1 item